# How to make 100% height columns with skeleton?

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I would like to have 2 columns that are 100% height, without using `<table>` and using the responsive columns from skeleton css.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
.column, .columns {
    min-height: 100%;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="ten columns alpha">
               bla bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="six columns omega">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

The container looks like it's 100% height but not the columns.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: If you want the columns to have the same height as the container, and you know those columns will always be within that container, then you should use `height:inherit`. Be mindful that this is not available in Internet Explorer 7, but since you're using `min-height` and not any fallbacks, it looks like you don't care anyway.

Comment: OP have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```